# help Simple Question

Tags: ms-access

run time error 2185
what's problem?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command9_Click()

Text10.Text = Val(Text7.Text) + Val(Text3.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the error message actually *say*?

Comment: you cannot reference a property or method  a control unless the control has the focus

Comment: You certainly can ... except for the Text property. This is a VBA special as a bound control has the Value property for the data value and the Text property for the actual content during focus until persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command9_Click()

Text10.value = Val(Text7) + Val(Text3)

End Sub